# "Most linked content" - a page has disappeared

Tags: google-search-console, links

So for my site, under "Most linked content" there is a whole list of pages, but one top page has recently disappeared. It used to be on the list with about 1000+ incoming links. Now it's totally gone.

Is this just something that happens? Or is there a reason behind it?

I've fetched the page and resubmitted it, which I assume will take a while to come back.

Thanks!

Comment: Give us more details about this page (url for example). Maybe your page has duplicate content. Did you check that ?

Comment: Oops late reply sorry. There's definitely no duplicate content. Have you heard of this issue before?

Comment: This issue can appear if your page has duplicate content. Google can consider this page as low quality page and make it disappear from its index.

Comment: There may be an issue with the quality of the links. Combined with a Penguin update, this could explain that.